# Computation of $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin(x)}{1-2a\cos(x)+a^2}\sin(nx) \, dx$

Tags: integration, fourier-series

How can I show, by means of Fourier analysis, that for every $a>1$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$

$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{\sin(x)}{1-2a\cos(x)+a^2}\sin(nx)\,dx=\frac{\pi}{a^{n+1}}?
$$

Answer (score 1):

There are four key ingredients:
$$ \sin(x)\sin(nx) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\cos((n-1)x)-\cos((n+1) x)\right]\tag{1} $$

$$ 1-2a\cos(x)+a^2 = (a-e^{ix})(a-e^{-ix}) \tag{2}$$
$$ \forall n,m\in\mathbb{Z},\qquad \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{nix} e^{-mix}\,dx = 2\pi\cdot\delta(m,n)\tag{3}$$
$$ \frac{1}{a-e^{ix}} = \sum_{n\geq 0} \frac{e^{nix}}{a^{n+1}}\tag{4} $$
An a (hopefully) illuminating example:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{e^{-10ix}}{(a-e^{ix})(a-e^{-ix})}\,dx&=&\frac{1}{a^2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-10ix}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{e^{nix}}{a^n}\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{e^{-mix}}{a^m}\,dx\\&=&\frac{2\pi}{a^2}\sum_{m\geq 0}\frac{1}{a^m}\cdot\frac{1}{a^{m+10}}\\&=&\frac{2\pi}{a^{12}}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{a^2}}.\tag{5} \end{eqnarray*}$$
Have a look at the [Poisson kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel), too.

Comment: In the second line of your derivation for $(5)$, I do not see why the sum goes to $10$. Should it not go to infinity as there are an infinite amount of pairs $n \geq 0$ and $m \geq 0$ such that $n-m-10=0$?

Comment: @IsaacBrowne: you are right, my fault, now fixing.